# Adding many symbol icons from geojson using a loop in Mapbox Android?

Tags: android, mapbox, geojson

I have a map with 500 symbol icons. I am wondering if there is a way to add these markers using a function or loop that iterates through my geojson info and grabs the needed features.  As it stands, I am adding each marker individually and it is making my mapbox activity several thousands of lines long.  It all works perfectly, but I feel like it would be good to clean up the code if possible.  Here is what I have so far:

adding my icon drawables I do this for every icon individually:

```
loadedMapStyle.addImage(
        Constants.ICON_ID_1_GREEN, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            this.resources, R.drawable.green_icon_1
        )
    )
```

Is there a way to add all these resources via a for loop or something else?

Then adding each icon via SymbolLayer and match expression:

```
loadedMapStyle.addLayer(
        SymbolLayer("route-location-layer-id", Constants.SOURCE_ID)
            .withProperties(
                iconImage(
                    match(
                        get("icon_property"), literal(Constants.ICON_ID_1_GREEN),
                        stop(literal(Constants.ICON_ID_41_GREEN), Constants.ICON_ID_41_GREEN),
                        stop(literal(Constants.ICON_ID_40_GREEN), Constants.ICON_ID_40_GREEN),
                        stop(literal(Constants.ICON_ID_39_GREEN), Constants.ICON_ID_39_GREEN),
                        stop(literal(Constants.ICON_ID_38_GREEN), Constants.ICON_ID_38_GREEN),
                        stop(literal(Constants.ICON_ID_37_GREEN), Constants.ICON_ID_37_GREEN),
                        stop(literal(Constants.ICON_ID_36_GREEN), Constants.ICON_ID_36_GREEN),

                        ),
                ),
                iconOpacity(0.0f),
                textField(get(Constants.ICON_NAME)),
                textColor(Color.WHITE),
                textVariableAnchor(
                    arrayOf(TEXT_ANCHOR_TOP)
                ),
                textJustify(TEXT_JUSTIFY_AUTO),
                textRadialOffset(.5f),
                textAllowOverlap(true),
                textSizePropertyValue,
                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconOffset(arrayOf(0f, -16.5f)),
                iconSize(
                    match(
                        toString(get(Constants.PROPERTY_SELECTED)),
                        literal(1.0f),
                        stop("true", 2.0f),
                        stop("false", 1.0)
                    )
                )
            )
```

For the sake of this post, I cut out a lot of the above code as it was repetitive code for each icon.

I used fromJson() method to convert the GeoJSON file into a usable FeatureCollection object

```
@get:Throws(IOException::class)
private val featureCollectionFromJson: Unit
    get() {
        try {
            // Use fromJson() method to convert the GeoJSON file into a usable FeatureCollection object
            featureCollection = "list_of_climbing_routes.geojson".loadGeoJsonFromAsset()?.let {
                FeatureCollection.fromJson(
                    it
                )
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            Log.e("MapBoxActivity", "getFeatureCollectionFromJson: $exception")
        }
    }
```

Lastly here is a snippet of my geojson code. I am accessing the coordinates and the icon_property properties of the geojson at this point:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Bump That",
        "climbingRouteNum":"1",
        "climbingRouteVRating":3,
        "climbingRouteBoulder":"Vandala Boulder",
        "area":"Front Area",
        "image_url":"https://routes/13/vandala_1_4.jpg",
        "ratingImageUrl":"https://routes/13/onestar.png",
        "climbingRouteBeta":"Another great squeeze problem. Stand start, surf to high sloping sidepulls, then squeeze your way continuously to better holds.",
        "vRating":"V3",
        "climbingRouteTickbox":"false",
        "selected":"false",
        "icon_property":"ICON_ID_1_GREEN"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [
         -86.30726135484986,
         33.92127026676458
        ]
      }
    },
```

I can post more code if needed. Thought this would be a good start. Thanks!!

OK so I'm wondering if I'm on the right track. I can't figure out how to get this to work with the stops, but I am able to use this looping function to get some information. I'm just not sure how to apply it in my match expression.  Here is my function:

```
        private fun getLoadingSymbolStops(): Array<Stop?> {
    val stops: MutableList<Stop> = ArrayList()
    val featureList: List<Feature> = featureCollection!!.features() as List<Feature>

    for (x in featureList.indices) {
        val iconProperty = featureList[x].getStringProperty("icon_property")

        stops.add(stop(x, x))

                Log.d("tag", "${stops.toTypedArray()}")
                Log.d("tag", iconProperty)
    }
    return stops.toTypedArray()
}
```

// also tried:

```
stops.add(stop(x, iconProperty))
```

// also tried:

```
stops.add(stop(iconProperty, iconProperty))
```

did not work either

Here is how I am trying to use it according to the mapbox example @Sergio linked me to.  Although it's not crashing, it's not setting any of my icon's either.  Here is my loadedMapStyle.addLayer code as it stands:

```
        loadedMapStyle.addLayer(
        SymbolLayer("route-location-layer-id", Constants.SOURCE_ID)
            .withProperties(
                iconImage(
                    match(
                        get("icon_property"), literal(Constants.ICON_ID_1_GREEN),
                        stop(literal(getLoadingSymbolStops()), getLoadingSymbolStops()),

                        ),
                ),
                iconOpacity(0.0f),
                textField(get(Constants.ICON_NAME)),
                textColor(Color.WHITE),
                textVariableAnchor(
                    arrayOf(TEXT_ANCHOR_TOP)
                ),
                textJustify(TEXT_JUSTIFY_AUTO),
                textRadialOffset(.5f),
                textAllowOverlap(true),
                textSizePropertyValue,
                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                iconOffset(arrayOf(0f, -16.5f)),
                iconSize(
                    match(
                        toString(get(Constants.PROPERTY_SELECTED)),
                        literal(1.0f),
                        stop("true", 2.0f),
                        stop("false", 1.0)
                    )
                )
            )
    )
```

Here is a snippet from my logcat:

```
D/tag: [Lcom.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression$Stop;@6dad284
D/tag: ICON_ID_1_GREEN
D/tag: [Lcom.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression$Stop;@d680a6d
D/tag: ICON_ID_2_YELLOW
D/tag: [Lcom.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression$Stop;@5c7d6a2
D/tag: ICON_ID_3_YELLOW
```

etc....

My Log is showing that i'm looping through all my icon_properties, which i need for the stops and i'm also showing that the function is returning stops.toTypedArray.  Where do I go from here?  Anyone?  Thanks!

Here is the code on stop from Expressions.java:

```
  public static Stop stop(@NonNull Object stop, @NonNull Object value) {
return new Stop(stop, value);
```

}

/**

- Produces discrete, stepped results by evaluating a piecewise-constant function defined by pairs of
- input and output values ("stops"). The `input` may be any numeric expression (e.g., `[\"get\", \"population\"]`).
- Stop inputs must be numeric literals in strictly ascending order.
- Returns the output value of the stop just less than the input,
- or the first input if the input is less than the first stop.
- 
- Example usage:
- 
- 
- {@code
- CircleLayer circleLayer = new CircleLayer("layer-id", "source-id");
- circleLayer.setProperties(
- ```
  circleRadius(
  ```
- ```
      step(zoom(), literal(0.0f),
  ```
- ```
      literal(1.0f), literal(2.5f),
  ```
- ```
      literal(10.0f), literal(5.0f))
  ```
- ```
  )
  ```
- );
- }
- 
- 
- @param input         the input value
- @param defaultOutput the default output expression
- @param stops         pair of input and output values
- @return expression
- @see [Style specification](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-step)
  */

Comment: As you stated, there are a lot of details hidden because of the code, but, there is a concept called Memoization, which is about saving a previous result in memory to avoid repeating a process, here there is an example about that [Memoization](https://jorgecastillo.dev/kotlin-purity-and-function-memoization)

Comment: Thank you Wilson, but I have no idea how to apply what's in that article to my code. It is too advanced for me.  Just hoping to loop through the geojson and get the icon_property data and apply it all in the expression in one fell swoop.  Or Perhaps I should move some of this code into another file/class and access it from my main activity?  Is that possible?  I'm sorry to be confusing. The code all works fine. It's just a lot of lines of code in one activity.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think Memorization would be to advanced. And probably not 100% sure it could be appropriate for this specific case. Back to your questions: (1) I'm quite confident your `loadedMapStyle.addImage()` could be iterated wit a For loop or similar if you previously define/add your images in your JSON. (2) Your stops maybe possible too. I've never faced too many POI's, so never tought about it. But, check this link: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbollayer-mapillary/ (specifically, code references to `getLoadingAnimationStops()`). Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Sergio I added my latest attempt up above.  It still didn't work, but maybe I'm headed in the right direction?  Thanks for your comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documents, **you should only need to provide the array of Stops**, not using the expressions changing the parameters. Should you try this:

```kotlin
loadedMapStyle.addLayer(
  SymbolLayer("route-location-layer-id", Constants.SOURCE_ID)
      .withProperties(
          iconImage(
             match(
                get("icon_property"),
                literal(Constants.ICON_ID_1_GREEN),
                // Instead of stop() based on array of stops, just add stops' array
                *getLoadingSymbolStops()
             ),
          ),
          /* Remaining Properties*/
      )
)
```

Comment: I had thought to try this answer previously, but when I do that I get an error on match that says:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
match(Expression, Expression, vararg Expression.Stop!) defined in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression
match(vararg Expression!) defined in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression

Comment: It seems the match expression is recognizing the getLoadingSymbolStops() as the first parameter of the stop expression instead of an array of stops.

Comment: @tommybomb Can you try specifiying `*getLoadingSymbolStops()` when calling? Notice the `*`. My bad, it is a Kotlin's `vararg` and it won't take the array itself. You need to unpack it when using as argument, with the spread operator (i.e., the `*`).

Comment: I tried that and it is now accepted by match.  However I still can't get it to show my icons.  I've tried a few different variations of stops.add, but the only one that does anything is this one:

stops.add(stop(literal(x), iconProperty))

however all markers show up as default ICON_ID_1_GREEN so seems it's not reading the return stops.toTyped array. I'm editing my post and adding the code for stop  in Expressions.java file if that's of any help.  Thanks so much for your help. this is giving me a headache!

Comment: stops.add(stop("Constants.$iconProperty", "Constants.$iconProperty"))

this is actually what look right and shows in my code as correct. However it does not show any icons when i run the code in the app.  Could it be because I have my ICON_ID strings in a separate Constants folder?

Comment: If you are adding it as `"Constants.$iconProperty"` (note your double quote `"`), are you sure they are being added as the expected value? I think they are being added as a String (i.e., `"Constants.$iconProperty"`), not as an interpolation (i.e., `"Constants.ICON_ID_XXX"`). That's my guess, not sure. Have you tried `stops.add(stop(iconProperty, iconProperty))`??

Comment: yes, I've pretty much tried every possible variation i could think of. All to no avail. I put in a request to @mapbox but not sure how they are with support.  Unfortunately unless someone swoops in with a strong mapbox background, I'm at a loss.  I'll keep trying some things today, but I feel like i'm just repeating the same attempts.  ugh.  The only thing I haven't tried is to move all my ICON_ID's out of the Constants file and into the MapboxActivity.  Not thinking that will work, but not sure what else to do.  Thank you for jumping in on this.

Comment: anyone from @mapbox care to chime in here?